# Register Callback endpoint with NetSuite CRM

Tags: netsuite

we have one requirement for updating/notifying enterprise applications about any/specific data change in NetSuite CRM.
I googled, but could not find, if NetSuite allows to register endpoint so that any update would be pushed to that registered endpoint. Is there any such configuration NetSuite CRM provides?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from purchasing an off the shelf integration package, there are two main ways to accomplish this. Both of them are not pretty.

1. Polling SuiteTalk. Poll SuiteTalk as a specified frequency for any updated records. I've implemented a ruby gem that provides most of this functionality out of the box. https://github.com/NetSweet/netsuite_rails
2. Writing User Event SuiteScripts. Using these scripts you can trigger a script to run, that script can call an external URL and pass the NS internalId & type of the record that was updated.

Answer (score 0):

sudhirk,

There's no mechanism for what you ask.  Netsuite allows for a lot of different ways to configure 'incoming' data.  (ie. RESTlets, SuiteTalk (WebServices), Suitelets, etc).  However, building a 'push' endpoint is nearly non existent.  If your external systems have simple HTTP GET options, you could use nlapiRequestURL to push data.  Otherwise, you're looking into a more formal integration project.  I do this daily in my job, and we prefer to use [BOOMI](http://www.boomi.com) as the middleware.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok Darren, If i got you correctly, you are saying that NetSuite can not push data(data add or data update) to any external systems. That means, external systems need to keep pulling data from NetSuite in which it is intrested in as a schedule job?

Comment: Essentially, yes.  However, you could also make use of the ODBC connector (optional/addon) from Netsuite.  It works well, but is read-only.